# Появляется ошибка SyntaxError(unicode error)'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, калькулятор, visual-studio-2022

Пишу калькулятор на python в visual studio 2022,

```
number1 = float(input('Введите первое число: '))
operator = input('Введите знак действий')
number2 = float(input('Введите второе число: ')
if operator == '+':
    result = number1 + number2
elif operator == '-':
    result = number1 - number2
elif operator == '/':
    result = number1 / number2
elif operator == '*':
    result = number1 * number2
print('Результат: ' + result)
```

Но когда запускаю этот код, то появляется ошибка :
number1 = float(input('??????? ?????? ??????: '))

(И ещё ^ указывает на вторую скобку с конца)

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Подскажите пожалуйста что означает эта ошибка, и как её исправить.

Comment: `number2 = float(input('Введите второе число: '))`  и `print(f'Результат: {result}')`

Comment: @S.Nick, увы, не помогло. (

Comment: Visual Studio 2022? Серьёзно?

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard, а что не так то?

Comment: Помогло:  файл -> сохранить как -> сохранить с кодировкой -> utf-8 -> сохранить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл надо сохранять в кодировке utf-8, а у Вас, похоже, 1251.

P.S. А еще в 3-й строке не хватает закрывающей скобки.